# Review problem?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I press review and see 3 items needing reviewing: 2 close votes, and 1  new post.

When I try to enter either one, I get the message There are no items for you to review.

What is the problem?

Comment: My money is on aggressive caching of those numbers

Comment: Does it persist when you reload the main /review page? I've seen caching issues under /review before.

Comment: yep, its still present after doing a browser reload...same counts are still present as my report too.

Comment: In fact, I cleared the browser cache AND restarted....results the same.

Comment: I have the same problem. Currently, it's two reopen reviews listed and none are displayed. Earlier, it was another category as well (I think new member posts). Switching to another browser (Chrome instead of FF) and logging in there didn't help.

Comment: I had this happen to me for the first time last night.

Comment: logged in on another computer and things seem ok here.....I don't know if I'd still see the problem my office computer or not again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there was a bug and it's fixed now: [Number of items needing review is a lie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165647/number-of-items-needing-review-is-a-lie)

Yes, this an answer, not a comment, even if trivial.